# Logic of fixed number of records per page alphabetical pagination structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, logic

The easiest way to explain this question is by example. See the following two images of the browse links on a particular website:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Basically, the way that it works is that there are a set number of records per page, and it works "backwards" in some manner to break down the browse pages into an appropriate number of ranges. So when there are relatively more records (as in the case of those starting with an "A"), there are more ranges, and more pages, than when there are fewer records ("X"). I am developing in Ruby on Rails, but would also be interested in some perspective on the logic here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to visualize this is to think about the "deepest" groups all having 10 elements each, so split all your records into groups of 10.
Now, each group of 10 should be referenced to by an upper level group.
Each group of 10 of those should be referenced to by an even higher level group.
Finally, you'll reach the highest level group.

For any group, you take the n first letters of the first and last elements in their tree where n is it's depth. So for a group in depth 1, you take the 1st character of the very first element (recursively go deeper until you are at the sparsest branches) as the start of its range and the 1st char of the last elements as the end of it's range.

I could mock it up in PHP if you would be able to get what you need from it, but can't quite grasp the concept here.

Comment: Thanks for this. The php mockup would actually be really helpful, as I'm not finding it terribly easy to translate this logic into code.